# ¿Cómo hacer que un input type number solo acepte números enteros sin puntos?

Tags: html

Necesito que un input type number solo acepte números enteros sin puntos, con ayuda de stackoverflow he logrado que solo acepte números pero no he podido evitar que acepte el carácter punto .

Este es mi input:

```
<input type="number" min="1" step="1" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount" name="quantity" placeholder="Cantidad" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*">
```

Sin embargo todavía puedo escribir el punto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Checa https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37043867/how-to-avoid-decimal-values-in-input-type-number/44379790

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te fijas se trata de filtrar la entrada de teclado, puedes hacerlo con un evento onkeydown(). Este evento debe llmar a una función que verificará la tecla pulsada y si se trata de '.' o 'e' (ambos caracteres considerados numéricos por javascript) pues interrumpe el evento y no agrega el valor.
Prueba este código que puedes también ver [funcionando aquí](https://javascript.espaciolatino.com/sols/form_input_int.htm)

```
<input type="number" min="1" step="1" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount" name="quantity" placeholder="Cantidad" onkeydown="filtro()">
</form>
<script>
function filtro()
{
var tecla = event.key;
if (['.','e'].includes(tecla))
   event.preventDefault()
}
</script>
```

Con esta solución mantienes el tipo de control para el input. No necesitas el pattern pues al ser un campo numérico está implicito: todos los dígitos más el punto decimal y la letra e (para notación científica).

Comment: Gracias me ayudo bastante

Answer (score 0):

En tu HTML le puse un **id** a tu input con

```
id="quantity"
```

Esto para agregar el evento **keypress** desde javascript

```
document.getElementById('quantity').addEventListener('keypress', function(evt) {
    if (filterInteger(evt, evt.target) === false) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

El evento ejecuta la función **filterInteger** para filtrar sólo los caracteres permitidos según la **tabla ASCII** https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/

Aquellos caracteres que no cumplan con el filtro **se cancela el evento** con

```
evt.preventDefault();
```

Lo cual sólo deja escribir **números enteros positivo**s en el input.

En la funcion **filterInteger** se detalla los caracteres permitidos y necesarios.

Código completo

```js
function filterInteger(evt,input) {
    // ASCII https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/
    // ‘0′ = 48, ‘9′ = 57, ‘-’ = 45
    // Backspace = 8, Enter = 13, NULL = 0
    var key = window.Event ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;    
    var chark = String.fromCharCode(key);
    var tempValue = input.value+chark;
    if((key >= 48 && key <= 57) /* || key == 45 */) {
        return filter(tempValue);
    } else {
        return key == 8 || key == 13 || key == 0;
    }
}

function filter(__val__) {
    // /^-?[0-9]*$/; // positivos y negativos
    // /^[0-9]*$/; // solo positivos
    var preg = /^[0-9]*$/;
    return preg.test(__val__);
}

document.getElementById('quantity').addEventListener('keypress', function(evt) {
    if (filterInteger(evt, evt.target) === false) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="number" min="1" step="1" class="form-control" id="quantity" aria-label="Amount" name="quantity" placeholder="Cantidad" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*">
</body>
</html>
```